Logging labeled messages to Sheets creates duplicates
The script below logs the date and subject of Gmail messages with a specific label then removes the label from the thread. I don't need any responses "RE:" or forwarded messages "FWD:" logged.
I have a few issues:

The script runs manually but I want it to run automatically every 30 minutes to an hour.
The script generates duplicates each time it pulls the labeled messages to the sheet. How do I get the script to only generate the new data?
I want the script to add a new label after it removes the old one so I can see which messages have been processed.

Script
function myFunction() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Label1");
  var threads = label.getThreads();

  for (var i=0; i<threads.length; i++)
  {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

    for (var j=0; j<messages.length; j++)
    {
  
      var sub = messages[j].getSubject();
      var dat = messages[j].getDate();

      ss.appendRow([dat, ,sub])
    }
      threads[i].removeLabel(label);
  }
}


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I assume you are applying the label using a Gmail filter and then removing it with the script once it's been logged.
The reason you are getting duplicates is that you are searching for threads and returning the messages in those threads.
Even if you remove the label from a thread, if a new message is received and labeled, every message in the thread is processed again.
For your use case, it might make more sense to search for and process messages instead of threads.
I repurposed a recent script for you. It will batch the message updates as well as the spreadsheet update. ie. It will write all the new rows for a batch at once rather than doing it for each message as they are processed.
the install_trigger() function will create a time-based trigger for the script. It is set for 15 minutes but you can tweak that as you see fit by changing the value in everyMinutes(15)
Instructions

Create and name a single sheet spreadsheet where you want the log.
Click on the Extensions menu then Apps Script
Paste the code the follows and save.
Click on Services in the left menu and scroll down and select GMAIL.
Test the script by running logMessagesByLabel from the editor.
If any errors make sure the user labels exist.
If running okay run install_trigger from the editor to setup the time-based trigger.

Script
/**
 *   +-------------------------------+
 *   |  Log Gmail Messages By label  | 
 *   +-------------------------------+ 
 * 
 *   v 1.0 2024-05-04
 *   v 1.2 2024-05-06
 *   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78427215
 * 
 */

const searchLabel = "_logme";        // Will find messages with this label then remove after processing. 
const addLabel = "_alreadylogged";   // Will add this label to processed messages 
const setTimeZone = "PST"
const dateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss";
const maxPerBatch = 250;            // Maximum messages to return per search (do not exceed 500) 
const maxBatchesPerRun = 4;         // Maximum searches to perform each time script is run


function logMessagesByLabel() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const labels = Gmail.Users.Labels.list('me').labels;
  const names = []; labels.forEach(l => names.push(l.name));
  const searchId = labels[names.indexOf(searchLabel)].id;
  const addId = labels[names.indexOf(addLabel)].id; 
  let batch = 0;
  listMessages();

  function listMessages(token) {
    batch += 1;
    console.log("Batch", batch, "starting (max " + maxBatchesPerRun + ")");
    const list = Gmail.Users.Messages.list("me", {labelIds:  [searchId], pageToken: token, maxResults: maxPerBatch });
    token = list.nextPageToken;
    const messages = list.messages;
    const ids = [], values = [];
    
    if (messages) {
      let counter = 0;  
      const last = ss.getLastRow();

      for (let i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
        counter +=1;
        let id = messages[i].id;
        ids.push(id);
        let hdrs = Gmail.Users.Messages.get("me", id, {format: "metadata", metadataHeaders: ["Date", "Subject"]}).payload.headers;
        let os = ((hdrs[0].name == "Date") && 1) || 2;       
        values.push([Utilities.formatDate(new Date(hdrs[-1+os].value),setTimeZone,dateFormat),,hdrs[2-os].value]);
      } 
      
      ss.getRange(last + 1,1,values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
      Gmail.Users.Messages.batchModify({"ids": ids, "removeLabelIds": searchId, "addLabelIds": addId }, "me");
      console.log("Batch", batch, "finished.", counter, "messages processed."  );
    } else {
      console.log("Batch", batch, "finished. No messages found."  )
    }   
    
    while ((token) && (batch < maxBatchesPerRun)) listMessages(token);
  }
} 

function install_trigger(){ 
  delete_triggers()   // avoids duplicates
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("logMessagesByLabel").timeBased().everyMinutes(15).create();
}


function delete_triggers(){
  ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().forEach(t => ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(t));
}```




I copied the script and changed the name of the label. Once I clicked to run it, I got an error message saying:
ReferenceError: Gmail is not defined
logMessagesByLabel
I also am only using this script for 1 singular label as well as having the time post in PST.

Is it possible to setup as to remove the existing label and change it to another, as to them not being lost in the whole inbox.

Sorry, I'm really not the greatest with this at all and I really appreciate you helping me. Which locations in this script need to be edited? Which spots do I need to rename to my actual labels? I assume that is the only data that needs changing besides altering the time zone and using a specific sheet.

I implemented the script to test it, it is working great so far, but the trigger to run every 15 minutes is not working. This is one of the most important parts of this script that I need.

Define "not working".  What happened when you ran the install_trigger function? Did you get an error in the execution log?  If yes, what? Does the trigger show up under the triggers menu in the script editor?

The trigger did not show up in the triggers menu. The script ran and after 15 minutes, it didn't run again. Been toying around with the script and haven't been able to get the trigger going yet..

I don't think you are instilling the trigger.  You need to change the function from the drop-down to run the right one.

We got it to work by manually adding in the trigger through the trigger menu. Couple trials and error and it works. Updating every minute. Ran into a few other snags, such as trying to add drop downs and check boxes to the sheet, but fixed those too.
Thank you so much for your help!!

Alright, so we tried to change the code on line 12, which is the line referring to the getActiveSheet. I need to change this to pick from a specific sheet now that the rest of the code is working. I tried to Google it and make the change myself, but it didn't work. Please help!!!!


You should delete comments that are no longer relevant.  2. See What should I do when someone answers my question?. 3. You shouldn't change requirements or add new questions after your question has been asked and answered. Ask a new questioon you can include a link to this one if it requires additional context.  Include the relevant code and any error messages you have logged.

